# Google Transliterate API not working in mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-translate

I have written a code that transliterates the textbox content into `Gujarati` using Google Transliterate API. It's working fine in the PC browser, it also works in the mobile browser UC browser. The problem I am facing is that, when I run the same code in the mobile Chrome browser, it doesn’t work.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Load the Google Transliterate API
  google.load("elements", "1", {
    packages: "transliteration"
  });

  function onLoad() {
    var options = {
      sourceLanguage: 'en',
      destinationLanguage: ['gu'],
      transliterationEnabled: true
    };
    if (google.elements.transliteration.isBrowserCompatible()) {
      alert('compatible');
      var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
      var ids = ["idTitle", "idContent"];
      control.makeTransliteratable(ids);
    } else {
      alert('not compatible');
    }
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
</script>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <label for="blogtitle">Title</label>
  <input type="text" id="idTitle" name="txtTitle" value="" required>
  <label for="content">Content</label>
  <textarea id="idContent" name="txtContent" required> </textarea>
  <input name="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Comment: how to got it fixed? @himadri

Comment: @JohnySharma I couldn't fix it. So, left this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Different applications sometimes require different behaviors for users with incompatible browsers. The Transliterate API provides a global method **google.elements.transliteration.isBrowserCompatible()** to check compatibility, but it does not have any automatic behavior when it detects an incompatible browser. For usability purposes, you should detect incompatible browsers and, if detected, display an error message.

Comment: I checked this option. Please refer my updated code. It says it is compatible but still not getting output.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. It working fine on chrome desktop but not on chrome mobile.